# Extracting, unpacking all the code from a decorator (Gooey) into a single script

Tags: python, wxpython

I was recently introduced to Gooey and loved it. With that said, I have a more complicated program that I have 80% of the way there with Gooey, but I would like to add some custom wx panels and non-default functionality. WXPython seems easy enough, but I was hoping to take what I have done in Gooey and convert it to a single WXPython script that I could add to instead of re-building it from scratch. I played with the `inspect` module and grabbed the Gooey source code. The latter works, basically building from scratch, but is time-consuming! It seems to me, at run time, there must be a single script that can be grabbed, I am just not sure how to go about this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, could you give us more details about your program? For example, what kind is it? How many scripts is it made of? What kind of audience is it for?

Comment: How do you want to deploy it? Is it for Windows users or Unix users?

Comment: Hello, it is an audience of one, for now. I automate my workflow in audio production. I have five processes that I have been combining into one script, plus a scheduler. I run both Mac and Linux (Ubuntu).